# Reconstructing sklearn image patches results in a blank image

Tags: python, scikit-learn, computer-vision

```sh
System:
    python: 3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]
executable: /Users/steve/miniconda3/envs/retinanet/bin/python
   machine: Darwin-18.2.0-x86_64-i386-64bit

BLAS:
    macros: SCIPY_MKL_H=None, HAVE_CBLAS=None
  lib_dirs: /Users/steve/miniconda3/envs/retinanet/lib
cblas_libs: mkl_rt, pthread

Python deps:
       pip: 19.0.3
setuptools: 40.8.0
   sklearn: 0.20.3
     numpy: 1.16.2
     scipy: 1.2.1
    Cython: 0.29.6
    pandas: 0.24.2
```

I'm trying to convert an image into patches, and then converting that back into an image and saving. There are two functions that seem to do this.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.image.extract_patches_2d

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.image.reconstruct_from_patches_2d

Using the following code, reconstructing the patches seems to just "blacken" the image and reduce the size (original image size is 31MB -- new size is 33KB). No color, nothing. Garbage.

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image as skl
image = Image.open('./myimage.tif')
image = np.array(image)[..., :3]
patches = skl.extract_patches_2d(image, (300, 300), max_patches = 250)
reconstruct = skl.reconstruct_from_patches_2d(patches, image.shape)
# i need this as uint8, as i'm saving it back into an image
# i tried using skimage.img_as_ubyte, but i recieve an error
reconstruct = reconstruct.astype(np.uint8)
Image.fromarray(reconstruct, 'RGB').save('./myimage.out.tif')
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? The patches returned from extract_patches_2d all have color and look good. So I would expect the reconstruction to behave the same.

Comment: Before you save the image, are the values between 0 and 255 or between 0 and 1?
Sometimes, this kind of issues are just a matter of getting the values in the expected value interval so that it saves and renders properly.

Comment: @Eskapp I pasted the outputs here: https://pastebin.com/ZCfzSZj6

The reconstruction just doesn't look right and I'm not sure why. In the end I'm trying to chop up an image into w x h x color. I'll feed those into Tensorflow and manipulate the crops (add the boxes, scores, etc). Then I want to put all of the crops back together.